# Azure blob storage createBlockBlobFromLocalFile() has Error : OutOfRangeInput

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-blob-storage

So I have this code to upload an image to `azure blob storage`.

```
var blobSvc = azure.createBlobService(config.BLOB_ACCOUNT, config.BLOB_KEY);

controllers.upload = function (req, res, next){

    req.pipe(req.busboy);
    var fstream;

    req.busboy.on('file', function (fieldname, file, filename) {

        fstream = fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + '/upload/' + filename);
        file.pipe(fstream);

        fstream.on('close', function () {
            blobSvc.createBlockBlobFromLocalFile('resources',
                    filename,
                    fstream.path,
                    function(error, result, response) {
                        if (error) {
                            res.send(error);
                            return;
                        }
                        res.send(result);
                    });
        });
    });
}
```

The path was `/var/www/html/foo-project/api/controllers/upload/ragnar.jpg`, the account name is all small letters no other characters so is the container name.

And the image sure is present on that path.

[image]

But im still getting this error.

```
{code: "OutOfRangeInput", statusCode: 400, requestId: "00d83e3f-0001-002f-2c40-8cf7a5000000"}
```

How do I fix this? Thanks for the help.

**EDIT:**

The full `response` :

[image]

Comment: Could you please provide your request URL and account name?

Comment: @ZhaoxingLu-Microsoft sorry I believe those are sensitive informations. Sorry.

Comment: Oh sorry, I should have been aware of that.

Answer (score 0):

There is an example using express framework for uploading blob via http request on Azure offical GitHub repository, please see the source code line 97 at https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-node/blob/master/examples/blobuploader/server.js#L97.

---

**Update**

For example, the HTML form as below.

```
<form action="/upload" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="title"><br>
    <input type="file" name="upload" multiple="multiple"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Upload">
</form>
```

Here is the code sample using [multiparty](https://github.com/andrewrk/node-multiparty/) package (`npm install multiparty`).

```
var multiparty = require('multiparty');

app.post('/upload', function (req, res) {
    var blobService = azure.createBlobService();
    var form = new multiparty.Form();
    form.on('part', function(part) {
        if (part.filename) {

            var size = part.byteCount - part.byteOffset;
            var name = part.filename;

            blobService.createBlockBlobFromStream('<container-name>', name, part, size, function(error) {
                if (error) {
                    res.send({ 'Error': error });
                }
            });
        } else {
            form.handlePart(part);
        }
    });
    form.parse(req);
    res.send('OK');
});
```

Comment: I followed the code the `form.parse()` callback has 3 params `err`,  `fields` and `files`. the `fields` returns empty `{}` thus the upload is again returning the same error `OutOfRangeInput` :/

Comment: Also, what kind of file should I upload from the form? Do I need to convert to something?

Comment: @TheGreenFoxx I update  a code sample for using the function `createBlockFromStream` with node package `multiparty`. The package `multiparty` parse the form data. Any concern, please feel free to let me know.

Comment: @TheGreenFoxx Any concern?